# Need help to Integration of Perf4J with log4j.properties

Tags: java, log4j, perf4j

I am trying to integrate Perf4j v0.9.16 with log4j v1.2.17.

Below is Utils class which has a method.

```
public class Utils {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Utils.class);

    @Profiled
    public String checkNullValueForString(Object obj)
    {
        String resultStr = "";
        if(obj != null)
        {
            logger.info("Object is not null.");
            resultStr = String.valueOf(obj);
        }
        logger.info("Resultstr is "+resultStr);
        return resultStr;
    }
}
```

Below is log4j.properties file:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /usr/home/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
org.perf4j.log4j = INFO

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File= logs/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

When i run the utils method its print the logger message but perf4j logger doesn't print.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Perf4J documentation

> the Profiled annotation by itself just marks a method for profiling -
>   it does not actually add any timing code. Instead, you must use an
>   aspect-oriented programming framework, such as AspectJ or Spring AOP
>   to inject timing aspects into your code.

There are aspect classes provided for both the above AOP frameworks. You just need to add some configuration files to get going.

Read the Perf4J documentation at http://perf4j.codehaus.org/devguide.html#Unobtrusive_Logging_with_Profiled_and_AOP to understand how to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved the problem. When i run the method i got the output like "start[1345313774310] time[43] tag[checkNullValueForString]" instead of tabular form as shown in Perf4J documentation. Please guide.